In a chess engine, how to avoid the breakage of the three-fold repetition rule
I am working on my chess engine [1]. My issue is that if I run the AI bots in [2] with the depth of 4 for both the bots, already after the 13th ply the game breaks the three-fold repetion rule. I have absolutely no idea how to program my engine to avoid going to the breakage of the rule in question.
Any advice?
References
[1] Chess.java
[2] The demo AI vs AI match runner here: ChessDuel.java.

You can set the engine so it evaluates every repeat position as 0. That way the player who has even the smallest advantage will try to avoid a repetition unless necessary. Is your current evaluation function valuing the position as 0 even without the repetition? Then you may want to make it consider some extra factors so that it gives either player a small advantage.

So my flaw is in the heiristic function I use? At the moment, I only consider presence and vulnerability of the pieces of the state to evaluate.

@coderodde Probably. If it sees way too many moves as the same you'll encounter problems like the one you describe. You may solve it by adding a draw avoidance factor (i.e: make repetitions -0.01 rather than 0) so that it prefers picking a different "equal" move over repeating

Would using Shannon’s heuristic function solve the issue?
